# Processing doesn't catches exceptions

Tags: exception, server, try-catch, processing

```
try
{
  println("Connecting to the server....");
  myClient = new Client(this, "192.168.0.185", 1111);
  serverworks = true;
  println("Connected to the server!");
  println(myClient);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  print("Exception: ");
  println(e);
}
```

In this case, it throws

```
Connecting to the server....
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:507)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:287)
    at processing.net.Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at G7D3T.checkbuttons(G7D3T.java:178)
    at G7D3T.draw(G7D3T.java:100)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2185)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$9.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1440)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:356)
Connected to the server!
processing.net.Client@2a3942d7
```

But if I want to catch that  specific exception (java.net.ConnectException), the code
doesn't even compiles:

```
catch(java.net.ConnectException e)
```

> Unreachable catch block for ConnectException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are just seeing a message but the exception is not thrown, otherwise you would not see the output "Connected to the server!".
Maybe your Client class is not throwing the exception but just printing it.

Answer (score 1):

> In the first case you are just seeing a message but the exception is
> not thrown, otherwise you would not see the output "Connected to the
> server!". Maybe your Client class is not throwing the exception but
> just printing it.

As it turns out, Processing doesn't likes to just throw theese exceptions in the "extra" classes, so the solution is to check if it is active

```
if (myClient.active())
{
  serverworks = true;
  println("\rConnected to the server! :D   ");
  println(myClient);
}
```